# Map face and face relationship in MaxScript

Tags: maxscript

I know that single vertex can be assigned to several map verticles and vice versa.

But, **does the faces and map faces has 1:1 relationship?**

I mean, assuming that mesh uses only map channel 1:

```
local facesCount = polyOp.getNumFaces ePoly
for f = 1 to facesCount do ( 
    ...
)

local mapFacesCount = (polyop.getNumMapFaces ePoly 1)
for u = 1 to mapFacesCount do (
    ...
)
```

**Will `f` and `u` iterate over same range?** I've tested it and it `mapFacesCount` was always equal `facesCount`, but I am not sure if it's true.

**Also, do faces indices and map faces indices correspond with each other?**

I mean, will `(polyOp.getFaceVerts ePoly 10)` return the vertices of `face #10` and `(polyOp.getMapFace ePoly 1 10)` will give me map vertices for the same `face #10`?

Or I cannot say it's still `face #10`? **If so, how to "connect" this data?** I want to get vertices' positions and vertices' map coordinates for given face.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes and yes, the number and indices of faces stay the same. Although you can have invisible edges define map seams when using editable mesh, it's a different case with editable poly which is not defined by triangle faces and instead has polygons of arbitrary degree. Because you cannot split a polygon like this, the polygon count and the order do not change.

It's vertices that basically define the map seams and layout and there can be up to *sum(face1VertCount..faceNVertCount)* vertices – and there can also be just one vertex for all the faces.